# Can I make a function non-interactive after it's been defined?

Tags: interactive

I'm defining a minor-mode not meant to be interactively activated. I'd like to use
`define-minor-mode` because it's very convenient, but the downside is that it always sets 
the mode function as interactive.

Is there a way to make an already-defined command non-interactive?

Comment: isearch toggle state minor mode? :)

Comment: @kaushalmodi Haha. No, `cider-debug-mode` actually. :-)

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: I recommend having a look at the macro `define-minor-mode` within `easy-mode.el`, most specifically at the line of code `(interactive (list (or current-prefix-arg 'toggle)))`.  You may wish to consider making a new macro by copying `define-minor-mode` and calling it something like `define-non-interactive-minor-mode` -- comment out the interactive statement above and implement any other additional modifications that you see fit.

Comment: Good question! I thought I recalled that there was a keyword or an optional arg that you could pass to the macro that would prevent inclusion of an `interactive` spec, but there apparently is none. You might consider filing an enhancement request: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. (I was mistaken, I think, because my macro `icicle-define-command` does accept such an optional arg. There are cases where you use the macro *to define a helper function* that is then used to define some commands. The helper does all the heavy lifting, and the commands that use it are wrappers that provide different contexts.)

Answer (score 5):

If it's ok, that the function isn't interactive in the first
place, something like this might work.

```el
(defmacro define-noninteractive-minor-mode (mode doc &optional
                                                 init-value lighter keymap
                                                 &rest body)
  `(cl-macrolet ((interactive (&rest _)))
     (define-minor-mode ,mode ,doc ,init-value ,lighter ,keymap ,@body)))
```